# How is this kind of subgraph called?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a certain directed graph, G, and one of its subgraphs, S, such that:

1. S is a strongly connected component of G,
2. There are no paths from nodes in S to the rest of G,
3. There is a path from every node in G to a node in S.

At least 1+2, and I would say 1+2+3, seem to capture an interesting kind of subgraphs: those that act as a sink for the rest of the graph, in the sense that a sufficiently long random walk starting anywhere in G is bound to end up in S, and (as per 2), stay there forever.

I haven't been able to find this kind of subgraph, or something in its vicinity, described in the literature. Is there a name for it, or something related?

Comment: You could call it the sink of the meta-graph of all the strongly connected components of $G$? More specifically, each vertex in the meta-graph represents the strongly connected components of $G$ and the neighborhood of such a vertex $v$ is determined by other strongly connected components that are reachable from vertices the component $v$ contains in $G$.

Comment: I think nobody would blame you for abusing the term and calling $S \subsetneq G$ a sink. Or Rome? Hotel California?

Comment: Don't know what it is called, but there is an interesting SPOJ problem on that concept http://www.spoj.com/problems/CAPCITY/